# add action on button in table view objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

[image: image showing error]

i have to add alert on button for this i want the action on the button to do soo i have writen this code to open the alert

```
        cell.btnCommentOption.tag = indexPath.row;
        if([Boomerang sharedManager].currentUser.user_id != comment.user.user_id){
            cell.btnCommentOption.hidden = YES;
            [cell.btnCommentOption addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        }
```

and the button action is

```
- (IBAction)btnCommentOptionsTapped:(UIButton*)sender {
    UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController
                                 alertControllerWithTitle:@"Share"
                                 message:@""
                                 preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];



    UIAlertAction* sharefeed = [UIAlertAction
                                actionWithTitle:@"Share feed"
                                style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                    [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
                                }];

    UIAlertAction* report = [UIAlertAction
                             actionWithTitle:@"Report"
                             style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                             handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                  [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
                             }];

    UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction
                             actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                             style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                             handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                 [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
                             }];

    [alert addAction:sharefeed];
    [alert addAction:report];
    [alert addAction:cancel];

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil]
}
```

i have error on the when i add action to the button kindly help me out the error is `No invisible @interface for UIImageView declears the selectors addTarget:action:forcontrolEvents`

Comment: what is the error

Comment: this one is correct `cell.btnCommentOption.hidden = YES;` or this one is correct `cell.btnCommentOption.hidden = NO;` if you call in inside the condition

Comment: updated kindly have a look

Comment: i have called the action from outside the condition but having the same issue

Comment: can you show the addtarget related to this `btnCommentOptionsTapped`

Comment: are you add the `addTarget:action:forcontrolEvents` for your imageview

Comment: kindly see the image attacted with question

Comment: You don't need to put `[alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];` inside the handler for every action, this happens automatically.

Comment: @HusnainAli - cell.btnCommentOption is the imageview or UIButton

Comment: as per error your btnCommentOption is UIImageView Type, pls set btnCommentOption class as UIButton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your action name iscorrect or not

```
[cell.btnCommentOption addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

or

```
[cell.btnCommentOption addTarget:self action:@selector(btnCommentOptionsTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

**update answer**

```
if([Boomerang sharedManager].currentUser.user_id == comment.user.user_id){
        cell.btnCommentOption.hidden = NO;
        [cell.btnCommentOption addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }else
     {
      cell.btnCommentOption.hidden = YES;
     }
```

and call your button action as

```
- (IBAction)didTapButton:(UIButton*)sender {
```

not

```
- (IBAction)btnCommentOptionsTapped:(UIButton*)sender {
```

**final Upate**

**"No invisible @interface for UIImageView declears the selectors addTarget:action:forcontrolEvents "**

the error says `cell.btnCommentOption is the UIimageview not a  UIButton`

> `UIImageView` is not a `UIControl` so it doesn't have the `addTarget:action:forControlEvents` method as part of its interface. You can use a gesture recognizer instead.

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method add this code

```
cell. btnCommentOption.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
cell. btnCommentOption.tag = indexPath.row;
 cell.btnCommentOption.hidden = YES;
 if([Boomerang sharedManager].currentUser.user_id == comment.user.user_id){
        cell.btnCommentOption.hidden = NO;
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(btnCommentOptionsTapped:)];
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[cell.btnCommentOption addGestureRecognizer:tap];

    }
```

and call the method as

```
- (void)btnCommentOptionsTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
```

Comment: this is not an issue i have done this many time and have the same error give at the last of my question

Comment: are you add the `addTarget:action:forcontrolEvents` for your imageview , if yes change your  `addTarget:action:forcontrolEvents` to Tapgesture ,

Comment: @HusnainAli - cell.btnCommentOption is the UIimageview or UIButton

Answer (score 0):

**"No invisible @interface for UIImageView declears the selectors addTarget:action:forcontrolEvents "**
This error occurs beacause addTarget method is of Button and you are trying to call it on UIImageView. Please check outlet reference in your custom cell.  reference attach to `btnCommentOption` is not Button but UIImageView.